# Storing last 3 scores?

Tags: python, list, append

I have tried to code saving the 3 most recent scores to a list and then appending that list to a main class list, creating a list of lists with each student and their scores as a separate list. The code manages to append the scores to an existing list however doesn't display the first score and deletes it before 3 scores have been added. Could someone help me?

```
Student = [] #new list created each time for student
max_scores = 3 #3 scores only at a time in the student's list

if ClassName == "10x1": #if student's input for class is 10x1
    for userName in Class10x1: 
        if userName in Student and len(str(score)) >= max_scores:
            Student.pop([1]) #removes second element in list
            Student.append(score) #adds most recent score
            break #stops code
        elif userName in Student and len(str(score)) < max_scores:
            Student.append(score)
            break
        else:
            Student.append(userName)
            Student.append(score)
            break
    Class10x1.append(Student) #student's list is appended to main class list
```

Above code is printed like this:

```
[[]]
[['Jagraj', 1], ['Jagraj', 1]]
[['Jagraj', 1, 3], ['Jagraj', 1, 3], ['Jagraj', 1, 3]]
```

However I wish to print it like this:

```
[['Jagraj', 0, 1, 3]]
```

And then once the student has a 4th test, the first score is removed so it becomes [['Jagraj', 1, 3, 5]] Is there a way to do this or do I have to reconstruct the way I am storing the data?

Comment: what does score looks like ? len(str(score)) is very disturbing to me

Comment: Its just an integer generated after the test has been taken

Comment: `len(str(score))` returns the number of digits of score. I don't think that is what you are trying to test. maybe `len(student) + 1 >= max_scores` ?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Camelcase notations in Python unless you're writing classes, which you aren't. It gets confusing while reading your code. Please read the PEP8 guidelines for naming conventions in Python. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Now for your question, you code seems a bit tough to read so I'll try to examine the problem you're facing.

First thing, don't use nested lists but instead use a dictionary (hashmap). Things will be easier to handle.

Let's say we have a dictionary object:

```
from collections import deque

a={"ishaan":deque(maxlen=3)}
a['ishaan'].append(1)
a['ishaan'].append(2)
a['ishaan'].append(3)
```

then all I need to do to add a score to this is:

```
new_score=5
a['ishaan'].append(new_score)
print(a)
```

This will print

```
{'ishaan':[2,3,5]}
```

So, now things are easier to deal with and I guess your query is also answered. I did not solve your question but I guess you can take a hint from this and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll implement dictionaries instead of lists, they seem to be easier to manipulate such as removing and adding data.

Comment: a `deque` with maxlen=3 would make it even easier to maintain only the 3 last results

Comment: That is true. Editing my answer. Thanks.

Comment: But when the program is run again, the dictionary isn't there anymore?

Comment: @Kaiylar, maybe its better you start a new question, because your problem is quite different from this. I'll also suggest you to read about databases or maybe writing data to file in python. In memory dictionaries won't persist outside the program scope.

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt it be way easier to store the full list of the grades in the student's object, and then to only allow it to print a part of it by indexes?

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, studentname):
        self.Name = studentname
        self.Grades = []

    def last3grade(self):
        return [self.Name, Grades[len(self.Grades)-1],Grades[len(self.Grades)-2],Grades[len(self.Grades)-3]
```

Comment: return [self.Name, self.Grades[-3:]] would be more readable ;)

Comment: @Jagraj Singh, `def last3grade(self): return [self.Name...`

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it and I've managed to implement dictionaries into my code, much much easier and efficient than list of lists. Cheers! @Dionys

Comment: @Dionsys wouldnt that return a list in a list?